# Query results displaying multiple times

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

**Im making a MTG card database for my class**

I have 5 tables:
`card` holds a `cardId`, `name`, `text`, `power`, `toughness`, `rarity`, `manacost`, `setId`, `CMC`.  cardId is the primary key

`color` holds a `colorId` and `color`. color is the string, colorId is the primary key
`type` holds a `typeId` and `type`. Type is a string, typeId is the primary key
`card_colors` is a linking table that holds entry pairs of `cardId` and `colorId`
`card_types` is a linking table that holds entry pairs of `cardId` and `typeId`.

How can I search for cards by name, and have their respective types and colors to show up in one row? Currently my query shows multiple entries of each card, one for every color.

Here's my current query:

```
 SELECT card.name, type.name, color.color
 FROM card, card_types, card_color
 JOIN type, color
 ON (card.cardId = card_types.cardId) AND (card.cardId = card_color.cardId)
 WHERE card.name LIKE "ENTER NAME HERE";
```

If you want to check it out you can find my .sqlite file here:
http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/446996/mtg_database.sqlite

Comment: Can you post your current SQL Query?

Comment: If the data in your table is correct, you are displaying exactly what you want. Are you actually after a crosstab, i.e. one row per card with multiple columns for types?

Answer (score 2):

The best I can do with the limited information you've provided:

```
select * 
from card_types 
join card
    on card_types.cardId = card.cardId
where cardId = 1 /* specify value */
```

You must show your table structure and much more to help you any further. I can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a condition linking card_type and type tables. with no condition you are multiplying the join of card and card_type by types.